# finding an item in a list using recursion python

Tags: python

Use recursion to write a function contains that consumes a list **seq** and a value item. Your function should produce **True** if **item** is an element of **seq** and **False** otherwise. Item in the seq can be any type of data ie. float, list/array, tuple etc.

I have this so far:

```
def contains (seq, item):
    if len(seq) == 0:
        return True
    elif len(seq) == 1 and (seq[0] == item):
        return True 
    else:
        if (seq[0] == item):
            return contains(seq [1:], item)
        else:
            return False


print (contains([10, 12, 13, 14 ], 10))
```

Comment: But do you have a *question*?

Comment: Wait, if `seq[0] == item` there's no need to go recursive: you just return True right away.

Comment: for the excersise i need to go recursive

Comment: `return item in seq` - using recursion for this case is [censored about 10 really things to say about such taks and teachers giving those] the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah, I don't get why so many teachers do this. There are simple problems that call out for recursion. Instead of giving one of those problems, they come up with a problem that calls out for a loop and demand that you do it with recursion. As a later exercise, to show you how recursion and loops are dual after you understand both of them, this would make sense, but as a first-week assignment teaching recursion for the first time? It's like they just want to mislead their students…

Answer (score 1):

Your logic here is mostly backward, but not quite entirely backward.

First, for an empty list, you're returning `True`. That's wrong—an empty list doesn't contain *anything*, so it doesn't contain `item`.

Next, for a size-1 list whose only element is `item`, you return `True`. That's correct. Probably not a necessary test, but correct.

Next, if the first element is `item`, you check the rest of the list. That's wrong—a list that contains `item` plus some other stuff contains `item`.

Finally, for anything else (a multi-element list whose first element is not `item`), you return `False`. That's wrong—a list that contains a bunch of stuff, one of those things not being `item`, may still contain `item`. Here's where you need to check the rest of the list.

If you turn this correct logic into code the same way you turned your incorrect logic into code, your code will work.

Comment: thanks but there was no need for the sarcasm im just a beginner; first week

Comment: @harryhairyhairhare there is no sarcasm. There is an explanation of what happens and what should happen.

Comment: There is no sarcasm in my answer. I told you what each of your four tests means, and why each of them are wrong. If you'd prefer that I lied and told you that you did everything right, you wouldn't have a solution to your problem.